# Why is it not possible to use both :base() and :this() in a C# constructor

Tags: c#

I have a default constructor in my class that initializes stuff.

I don't want copy/paste that into another constructor I have that needs to have `:base(otherStuff)` on it.  I am guessing I will have to (or abstract it out to a method or some such thing).

**But I am wondering, why are both not supported?**

(Sometimes when I want something that the language does not support it means I am doing something wrong.)

Example:

```
public class SomeClass : SomeBase
{
      public SomeClass()
      {
          // Init a lot of lists and stuff
      }

      public SomeClass(OtherThings otherThings): base(otherThings)
             // :this()  <----- This is not legal syntax
      {
          // Do stuff with otherThings
      }
}
```

Comment: Simple fix, put the common logic in a function that both call. Good question though! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reasoning for this is the fact that base constructor is **always** executed before executing **any** constructor of your type which means that deriving from existing construtor `c1()` of your type already embedds deriving from base construtor `b1()` - and you obviously can't derive from 2 different base constrructors.

It's a bit confusing as `this()` constructor actually derives from `base()` constructor **implicitly**, so your code is equivalent to :

```
public class SomeClass : SomeBase
{
      public SomeClass(): **base()**
      {
          // Init a lot of lists and stuff
      }

      public SomeClass(OtherThings otherThings): base(otherThings)
             // :this()  <----- This is not legal syntax
      {
          // Do stuff with otherThings
      }
}
```

now it is obvious that you can't have `SomeClass(OtherThings otherThings): base(otherThings):this()` as compiler would not be able to execute 2 base constructors (`base(otherThings)` and `base()`).

---

**UPD:**
Thinking of why it is prohibited to depend on 2 constructors I came into this example:

```
public class SomeBase {
    public SomeBase(){}

    public SomeBase(OtherThings otherThings):this(){}
}

public class SomeClass : SomeBase
{
      public SomeClass(): base()
      {
          // Init a lot of lists and stuff
      }

      public SomeClass(OtherThings otherThings): base(otherThings)
             // :this()  <----- This is not legal syntax
      {
          // Do stuff with otherThings
      }
}
```

Allowing to have `SomeClass(OtherThings otherThings):base(otherThings):this()` would result in `SomeBase()` being executed twice which is ridiculous and unexpected (once for `:base(otherThings)` and the other time for `SomeClass(): base()` which both depend on parameterless constructor `base()`).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly why, but I had similar in the past and had to resort to something like...

```
public class SomeClass : SomeBase
{
      public SomeClass()
      {
          // Init a lot of lists and stuff
          CommonStuff();
      }

      public SomeClass(OtherThings otherThings): base(otherThings)
      {
          CommonStuff();

          // Do stuff with otherThings
      }

      private void CommonStuff()
      {
         // init common between both
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this situation:

```
class Base 
{
    public Base() { }
    public Base(string s) { }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived() : base("default") { }
    public Derived() : base()
                     : this() { }
}
```

It should be clear that this is guaranteed to cause trouble if it were allowed. Which base constructor would end up getting invoked?

Solutions have already been provided: extract it out to a method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty solid reasoning behind this - your base class shall be fully initialized before you start doing constructor stuff in derived type.

From your example it looks like you have two separate ways of initializing one class - perhaps yous shall consider changing your architecture for simpler one?

If that is not possible you might indeed like to use initialization method or chain your constructors like:

```
    class A
    {
        // no longer needed
        //public A()
        //{

        //}

        public A(SomeStuff stuff)
        {
            if (stuff != null)
            {
                // init stuff
            }
        }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public B() : this(null)
        {

        }

        public B(SomeStuff stuff) : base(stuff)
        {
            if (stuff != null)
            {
                // init stuff more
            }
        }
    }
```

In this situation your construction chain is proper - `this.default() -> this.specialized(null) -> base.specialized(null)`.

Of course, if `A()` is doing anything important you might keep it and just call from `A(SomeStuff)`.